# expand a data frame from the min to the max value of each column

Tags: r, dplyr

The reproducible data below contains random values for 2 covariates (`cov1` and `cov2`), 2 animals (`Cat` and `Dog`)  and 2 seasons (`Summer` and `Winter`).

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(Season = rep(c("Summer", "Winter"), each = 100),
                  Species = rep(c("Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog"), each = 50),
                  cov1 = sample(1:100, 200, replace = TRUE),
                  cov2 = sample(1:100, 200, replace = TRUE))

head(dat)
  Season Species cov1 cov2
1 Summer     Cat   29   24
2 Summer     Cat   79   97
3 Summer     Cat   41   61
4 Summer     Cat   89   52
5 Summer     Cat   95   41
6 Summer     Cat    5   89
```

I want to create a new df that contains a sequence from the min to the max value for each Season/Species combination. My initial thought was to first use `dplyr` to identify the the min and max values.

```
RangeDat <- dat %>% group_by(Season, Species) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(min, max)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

> RangeDat
  Season Species cov1_min cov2_min cov1_max cov2_max
1 Summer     Cat        3        5      100       97
2 Summer     Dog        1        1       99       99
3 Winter     Cat        2        1       99      100
4 Winter     Dog       12        2       99      100
```

From here I am not sure how to expand the df. Ideally the result df would have 4 columns (Season, Species, cov1, cov2). The values for `cov1` and `cov2` would range from the min to the max value for each Season/Species combination. Like the initial `dat` df, the values for `Season` and `Species` would repeat down the df for the increasing values of `cov1` and `cov2`.

In reference to the comments, is it possible to include an NA value where the length of a Species/Season combination is less than the 'maximum' range?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to account for the changes in length?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I want them to be the same. For example `length.out` would be the same for each Season/Species combination and each covariate. .

Comment: Yes, that is true, but if the min:max is different (as is the case here), the length won't be the same.

Comment: For example, `Summer - Cat - cov1` has range of 97, `Summer - Cat - cov2` has range of 92.

Comment: I was hoping there was a solution that would change the sequence increment so that the length would be equal.

Comment: ok, but you still need to decide how to handle that. Do you want to use the 'maximum' range and make every combination adhere to that?

Comment: Is it possible to have NA values for those Season/Species combinations where the sequence length is less than the 'maximum' range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `summarise` in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(Season, Species) %>% 
    summarise(cov1 = list(min(cov1):max(cov1)), cov2 = list(min(cov2):max(cov2)))
```

---

or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(cov1 = list(min(cov1):max(cov1)),
               cov2 = list(min(cov2):max(cov2))), by = .(Season, Species)]
```

#### Update

As the OP mentioned about keeping the `length` same by padding with `NA`, one option with `dplyr` would be

```
f1 <- function(x1, x2){
         x1 <- min(x1):max(x1)
          x2 <- min(x2):max(x2)
          m1 <- max(c(length(x1), length(x2)))
          length(x1) <- m1
          length(x2) <- m1
          list(cov1 = x1, cov2 = x2)
         }

dat %>%
    group_by(Season, Species) %>% 
    do(data.frame(Season = .$Season[1], Species = .$Species[1],  f1(.$cov1, .$cov2)))
# A tibble: 396 x 4
# Groups:   Season, Species [4]
#   Season Species  cov1  cov2
#   <fctr>  <fctr> <int> <int>
# 1 Summer     Cat     3     5
# 2 Summer     Cat     4     6
# 3 Summer     Cat     5     7
# 4 Summer     Cat     6     8
# 5 Summer     Cat     7     9
# 6 Summer     Cat     8    10
# 7 Summer     Cat     9    11
# 8 Summer     Cat    10    12
# 9 Summer     Cat    11    13
#10 Summer     Cat    12    14
# ... with 386 more rows
```

and the possible extension with `data.table` would be

```
setDT(dat)[, f1(cov1, cov2), .(Season, Species)]
#     Season Species cov1 cov2
#  1: Summer     Cat    3    5
#  2: Summer     Cat    4    6
#  3: Summer     Cat    5    7
#  4: Summer     Cat    6    8
#  5: Summer     Cat    7    9
# ---                         
#392: Winter     Dog   NA   96
#393: Winter     Dog   NA   97
#394: Winter     Dog   NA   98
#395: Winter     Dog   NA   99
#396: Winter     Dog   NA  100
```

Comment: I have added some specifics to the question to deal with difference in length and the desired result. I am not sure how to convert the `dplyr` result to a data frame structure in long format. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: @B.Davis  Updated the dplyr method